# 3 buttons in my webpage are not accessible using iOS Voiceover

Tags: ios, web, accessibility, voiceover

I have a webpage made with Stencil in typescript. In which I have 3 buttons within a div(role=main). While testing for accessibility in iOS device(Safari browser), the control is not ever going to those buttons. They are not clickable at all. It is entire skipping them. I am not getting enough help/community support regarding it's documentation, hence wondering if anyone has ever faced such issue and was able to fix it?

Code snippet:

```
<main role="main">
  <h1 class="sr-only">App Title</h1>
  <div class="card" role="main">
    <button
      aria-labelledby="of-title of-body"
      class="buttonClass"
      id="Button1"
      tabIndex={0}
      onClick={this.OptionClicked.bind(this)}>
      <div>
         <span class="type1Span">
           <svg
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             width="24"
             height="24"
             viewBox="..."
             class="type1Span">
             <path fill="#FAFAFA" fill-opacity="1.000" d="..."/>
             <path fill="#3A3A38" fill-opacity="1.000" d="..."/>
           </svg>
         </span>
         <h2 id="type1-title">{this.Constants.type1}</h2>
      </div>
      <span id="type1-body">{this.Constants.type1subtext}</span>
    </button>
    <button Similarly 2/>
    <button Similarly 3/>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Sounds like the `<div>` container might have `aria-hidden="true"`, which would hide all the contents from a screen reader.

Comment: You also might have to enable the "tab to all elements" feature in Safari.  By default, I think you can only tab to input fields.  Bring up safari preferences > advanced and check the "Press TAB to highlight each item..." checkbox.

Comment: @slugolicious The div doesn't have anything like aria-hidden. The buttons have tabindex=0. And nothing looks suspicious there. I wanted to enable the "Tab to all elements" feature, but can't find that in iOS mobile device. Also I just tried to repro this in a MacBook(Safari), I can't seem to access those buttons via Down arrow with VoiceOver on, rest everything seems accessible. So looks like that's the problem. But tab works just fine.

Comment: If you’re on iOS, then tabbing doesn’t matter unless you have a Bluetooth keyboard. You’re saying swipe right with voiceover is not going to the buttons? That only happens with aria-hidden. Can you post your code?

Comment: What happens if you set your rotor to “buttons” and then swipe down?

Comment: Can you post your generated HTML code please ?

Comment: Please post a snippet or a link to the site in the comments, there are loads of reasons the buttons may be skipped so it is difficult to help without something to look at / test against.

Comment: Attached code snippet in the question

Comment: @slugolicious Actually, when I open this webpage in a Safari browser with Voice Over in iOS device, I am not even able to click on these buttons. They are completely inaccessible.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code that would prevent the button from being selected. From an HTML validation perspective, you're not allowed to have a heading (`<h2>`) inside of a `<button>` but I wouldn't think that that would cause the button to not be selectable. (Button elements can only contain "phrasing content", https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2, of which headings are not part of. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element:phrasing-content-2-3)

Comment: If I copy/paste your code example as is without any of the classes or IDs referenced in `aria-labelledby`, and try in Safari with Voiceover, I get a funny looking button but I can swipe to navigate to it.